# How to restore a mozbackup file made in windows 7?

Tags: firefox, backup

I made a complete backup of Firefox, I used [mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/), while on windows 7. How do i restore a mozbackup made archive(.pcv) in Ubuntu using Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but assuming mozbackup is just an archive, rename the pcv extension to zip, extract it and move the files to your profile folder.

Your profile is located under: `~/.mozilla/firefox/*****.default/`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the support section of the website there is no version for linux,

> Where is a Linux or Mac OS X version? Sorry, no versions for Linux and
>   Mac OS X. I don't have plans for doing these versions.

Ref: [Mozbackup FAQ](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/support.php#linux-mac)

Without trolling through the site to see which format the program backs your data up I would recommend backing up your profile from firefox then restoring it in Ubuntu.

There is a very detailed support section from [Mozilla here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux) on how to achieve this.

Comment: what i mean is the mozbackup .pcv file can be extracted with file-roller which firefox directory do i unpack it in.

Comment: I don't know how Mozbackup works but assuming the .pcv file is readable by any version of firefox you will need to put it into the profile folder - the Mozilla site link has further details on how to find it.